# g++ - how to use -std=c++14 be default?

Tags: compiling, c++, g++

I want g++ to use -std=c++14 by default without having to type it every time. How would I do this?

Comment: Are you using a Makefile?

Answer (score 4):

put:

```
alias g++='g++ -std=c++14'
```

in your profile (or maybe `.bashrc`). The next time you log in (or start a new terminal, with `.bashrc`), the command `g++` will run `g++ -std=c++14`.

For a single terminal instance only, just type that on the command line. This will work in most cases, but if you have problems, try the below.

---

If you have scripts or programs that refer to the literal path to the `g++` binary (like `/usr/bin/g++`), would be to move the `g++` binary to a new file name, like `g++-bin`, and write a script like this named `g++` in the same directory:

```
#! /bin/sh
/usr/bin/g++-bin -std=c++14 "$@"
```

This will have the same end result as an alias (`$@` passes all arguments of the parent script to the `g++` binary), but will make the script be used when referring to the full path to the compiler.

Be sure to make the script executable (`chmod 755` or similar) if you use this method.

Also be aware that your package manager will overwrite your g++ script when g++ updates if you put the script in `/usr/bin` (or your distro's equivalent), so you might want to put the script in a different directory of higher precedence in your `PATH` variable.

I personally made a directory in my home dir (`~/bin`) just for this kind of thing, and have lines in `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` that prepends `$HOME/bin` to the beginning of the `PATH` variable:

```
PATH="$HOME""/bin:""$PATH"
export PATH
```

Comment: Note that this won't reliably work if g++ is invoked from a script or Makefile. Also, for OP's information, it would probably be wiser to name the alias something other than `g++`. The standard solution however is to use a Makefile, without a shell alias, as @JeffSchaller observes. Shell aliases are worth learning, though: they save typing time at the command line.

Comment: @thb it would be reliable if only you planned to run the script. Don't share this with others and expect it to work. And you can always un-alias it when needed with `alias g++=''`. But yeah, it's not something I do usually. If I have to type something a ton, I do though. (e.g. `alias wget='wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0 Seamonkey/2.42"'`)

Comment: You are a genius. Though, would love to know if there's new version of g++ which uses c++14 by default.

Comment: With this solution you can't compile with older standards. eg. `g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp` is expanded to `g++ -std=c++14 -std=c++11 foo.cpp`; and `gcc`/`g++`, when given multiple `std` flags, will use the newest standard (of the flags given; in this case `c++14`).

Comment: @Elliott you can always run `unalias gcc`/`unalias g++` for that case. Or make your wrapper script detect user-specified `std` values and override the default you've set.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the C++ Standards Support in GCC page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14), C++14 is the default for GCC 6.1 and later:

> This mode is the default in GCC 6.1 and above; it can be explicitly selected with the `-std=c++14` command-line flag, or `-std=gnu++14` to enable GNU extensions as well.

In current distributions, you shouldn’t need to do anything. (GCC 6.1 was released in late April 2016.)